# Is it possible to change look and feel of android app which is based on facebook?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which is Facebook based. It uses Facebook SDK. I don’t want to to show the Facebook look and feel to the user, instead the user should see the screen which I have designed. Is it possible? Can this app be a standalone or it will be called as facebook application only?
Please provide me some guidelines.

Thanks.